# Jasmine src_file wildcard usage in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jasmine

I'm having an issue when it comes to requiring individual Javascripts for Jasmine file. My application.js.coffee file doesn't include require_tree as I am loading page specific javascript in a  tag in each view.

I added this:

```
src_files:
  - assets/application.js
  - assets/*.js
```

which does not seen to load any JS files that are located in assets/. However, the files are clearly there because if I use

```
src_files:
  - assets/application.js
  - assets/feedback.js
```

The feedback.js file is loaded correctly and the test passes. Why does the wildcard not load the files in directory? Also assets/**/*.js doesn't work either for folders.

Answer (score 0):

When the jasmine gem looks up your files on disk it uses `Dir.glob` to expand out the wildcards (`*`) in the path. In the case that `Dir.glob` doesn't find any files, and the path specified doesn't have any wildcards in it, then jasmine will just add that file anyways. This basically assumes you're using sprockets and this will work.

This means, if all of you top-level includes are coffescript files they won't actually match `*.js`.

You can either:

- Add an additional top-level `.js` file that includes all of your javascript and use that in `jasmine.yml`
- Add each of your top-level files to `jasmine.yml` individually
- Add a `*.js.coffee` rule to you `jasmine.yml` and then a negative matcher to remove things you don't want.

The last option would look something like this (the `!` tells jasmine to remove files matching this glob from the list of files to include):

```
src_files:
  - assets/application.js
  - assets/*.js.coffee
  - !assets/subfolder/*.js.coffee
```